# How to mock a class that has a method that returns nothing, using Spock

Tags: java, testing, groovy, spock

I am currently attempting to set up Spock testing for a class that I created that has a method that returns nothing.

```java
public final class Test implements ITest {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(test.class);

    private DataSource testSource;

    public Test(DataSource testSource) {
        testSource = testSource;
    }

    public void validateFile() {

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("validating file");
        }

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.getValues(testSource);
    }
}
```

Above is the test I want to Spock test, and I only want to test this class and not the Handler class that has the method getValues.

This is my test mock class:

```
def "test buildConfig"() {
    given:
    DataSource testSource = Mock()
    Handler handler = Mock()
    Test test = new Test(testSource)
    when:
    test.validateFile()
    then:
    1 * handler.getValues(_)
}
```

But I get a null pointer exception, because handler.getValues does some logic in that method that I have not provided, it seems. But I don't care about the class: I just want to test that when I run validateFile method in test class, it creates a Handler and calls the getValues method on the handler.

Comment: I don't think your challenge has to do with mocking a method that doesn't return anything.  I think your challenge is related to the fact that you are trying to provide a mock `Handler`, but the implementation of `validateFile` is creating its own.  The local one you create in the test will be of no consequence.

Comment: Hmm yes that makes sense but how would I in the spock framework claim that I am expecting a new Handler object to be created when running validateFile(). 1 * Handler handler is not valid spock

Comment: "how would I in the spock framework claim that I am expecting a new Handler object to be created when running validateFile()" - That is a wholly different question than the one asked above but if what you really want to do is make claims about a new instance being created, you should look at https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#MockingConstructors.

Comment: If you want to make it testable then you need a way refactor your code, the easiest way would be to pass in a `Supplier<Handler>`, this way you can then inject the mock during testing.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown, the section about mocking constructors and static methods in Spock only applies to Groovy code under test, not to Java, Scala, Kotlin or whatever other language application might be written in. So refactoring for testability is the best way to go, if you want to avoid using tools like Mockito, the outdated PowerMock or my own pet Sarek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your class creates its own `new Handler()`, it's not using the Mock you created.

To be able to verify this, you'll need to refactor your class to be more testable.

### Pass in the Handler

First, let's look at passing a Handler into the method:

```java
public final class Test implements ITest {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(test.class);

    private DataSource testSource;

    public Test(DataSource testSource) {
        testSource = testSource;
    }

    public void validateFile(Handler handler) {

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("validating file");
        }

        handler.getValues(testSource);
    }
}
```

Now we can pass our mock into our validateFile call and verify it successfully:

```
def "test buildConfig"() {
    given: 'a datasource, handler and Test'
    DataSource testSource = Mock()
    Handler handler = Mock()
    Test test = new Test(testSource)

    when: 'we validate our file'
    test.validateFile(handler)

    then: 'our handler was invoked'
    1 * handler.getValues(_)
}
```

### Use a Supplier

If we really want the Handler to be created inside the method, then we can pass in a `Supplier<Handler>` as per the comment from @leonard-brünings

As an alternative to changing the verifyFile() signature, this time, let's rewrite our constructor to take a Supplier as an argument and store our function as a field:

```java
public final class Test implements ITest {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(test.class);

    private DataSource testSource;
    private Supplier<Handler> supplierOfHandler;

    public Test(DataSource testSource, Supplier<Handler> handlerSupplier) 
    {
        testSource = testSource;
        supplierOfHandler = handlerSupplier;
    }

    public void validateFile() {

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("validating file");
        }
        handler = supplierOfHandler.get()
        handler.getValues(testSource);
    }
}
```

... and then set up our test with a supplier that returns a Mock Handler, that we can then use to verify interactions:

```
def "test buildConfig"() {
    given: 'a datasource, handler and Test'
    DataSource testSource = Mock()
    Handler handler = Mock()
    Test test = new Test(testSource, () -> handler)

    when: 'we validate our file'
    test.validateFile()

    then: 'our handler was invoked'
    1 * handler.getValues(_)
}
```